# Shoring up a cracked picture window for winter?

Tags: windows

My mom's house has a large picture window that was cracked last summer while the foundation was being repaired. We're getting it replaced with a bay window, but the company won't be able to actually do that until next year.

We just had the first bad storm of winter, and the crack in the window grew longer, so we're worried it will break completely over the winter.

It's taped up now, but is there anything else we can do to help make sure it survives the next few months?

Comment: Would cover the outside with plywood or maybe plexiglass if you can get a big enough sheet.  Tape won't hold.  Covering the inside also will prevent glass going everywhere if it does break(surprise it has not already).

Comment: Is it a double-paned window? If so, is the crack on the inside or the outside pane, or both? The reason I'm asking is if this is for safety reasons or are you asking only to keep the winter cold outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For primary protection against the wind, a clear acrylic sheet fastened to the outside wall & sealed with decorator's caulk - this is not great outdoors long-term, but might be easier to get off in spring than regular outdoor mastic or silicone sealant.
Acrylic sheet will actually deform in the wind, so if you seal the edges completely, it may cause further compression against the glass. It might be wise to leave a little breathing room by not completely sealing the bottom edge.

For secondary protection - & also has some heat-retention properties - UV window film [Random Amazon search](https://www.amazon.co.uk/UV-Window-Film/s?k=UV%20Window%20Film). Applied to the inside it will add some safety if the window does actually fail, like a poor-man's laminated glass substitute.

It is removable, so if all survives the winter, you could add a bit of sun protection there or elsewhere in the house for summer.

*After other answers* - I didn't realise you could get shatterproof film for a similar price to UV/mirror film, I'd assumed it would be far more expensive. The difference is thickness, strength & tear resistance. If you can get shatterproof in budget, get that instead.

*Fitter's note:*
This stuff is awkward to work with. Though it has no adhesive as such, it will cling to itself as you try to install it, more than you could imagine possible - think of handling a 6ft square of cling-film/saran wrap, then imagine if it is actually sticky too… and also covered in soapy water. Anything larger than maybe 3ft square is a two-man job.

Comment: How would you fasten it? Just nails?

Comment: If you have a wooden frame - *however* you will have to pre-drill the acrylic *and* use big washers, with rubber underneath ideally. It is *soooo* easy to break. Screws would be more controllable.

Comment: BTW, after other answers, i didn't realise shatterproof film can be got for almost the same price as UV. The difference is thickness, strength & tear-resistance. if you can get shatterproof in budget, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

**Shatterproof window film** ( or **security window film** or **hurricane window film**) is a product.

Applied to the inside surface, it will hold the glass together even if quite broken.

Answer (score 0):

Go to big store that sells clear acrylic panels. They come in 4x8 foot size or smaller. Durable and impact-resistant for prolonged use. 1/8 in. thickness yet stronger than glass. They might cut it to your size.

The glass might continue to crack, but now you are protected from complete failure. If you want more go to car glass repair and ask for type of glue they use to seal the cracks.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago, in public buildings in UK, all glass had to be fitted with a sheet of thin acrylic sheet - applied cut to size, with water and a squeegie. It was as H&S obligation, that effectively turned float glass into a sort of laminated glass. That solved the broken glass falling out in shards and cutting the person who fell into it, or shattering when a brick was thrown at it. That, certainly on the broken side, is a start point, maybe put onto both sides.